# converting string (strtold) to long double and subtracting from long double gives > epsilon

Tags: c++

Not sure if anyone has run into this and can help find a solution to this.

Basically I m converting a string to a floating point value and then subtracting from a floating point value to see if difference is within +/- epsilon

Question is what I am doing wrong to get a different result for long double?

It looks like the difference between the 2 long doubles is yielding a value with precision that of float but not sure why...

The output from the code (both mac and linux 64 bit  gave the same result)

```
float        : a=145.568 d=145.568 epsilon=1.19209e-07 fabsf(a - d)=0 equal? equal
double       : b=145.568 e=145.568 epsilon=2.22045e-16 fabs(b - e)=0 equal? equal
long double  : c=145.568 f=145.568 epsilon=1.0842e-19 fabsl(c - f)=5.41234e-15 equal? not equal
```

here is the code

```
#include <limits>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>

template <typename T>
bool cmp_equal(const T& lhs,
               const T& rhs,
               const T& epsilon = std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon()) {
    const T diff = (lhs - rhs);
    return ((diff >= -epsilon) && (diff <= epsilon));
}

int main()
{
    float a = 145.5678f;
    double b = 145.5678;
    long double c = 145.5678l;

    std::stringstream s("145.5678 \r\t\n");
    char* end;

    float d = std::strtof(s.str().c_str(), &end);
    double e = std::strtod(s.str().c_str(), &end);
    long double f = std::strtold(s.str().c_str(), &end);

    std::cout << "float        : " << "a=" << a << " d=" << d
              << " epsilon=" << std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()
              << " fabsf(a - d)=" << std::fabsf(a - d)
              << " equal? " << (cmp_equal(a, d)?"equal":"not equal")
              << std::endl;

    std::cout << "double       : " << "b=" << b << " e=" << e
              << " epsilon=" << std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()
              << " fabs(b - e)=" << std::fabs(b - e)
              << " equal? " << (cmp_equal(b, e)?"equal":"not equal")
              << std::endl;

    std::cout << "long double  : " << "c=" << c << " f=" << f
              << " epsilon=" << std::numeric_limits<long double>::epsilon()
              << " fabsl(c - f)=" << std::fabsl(c - f)
              << " equal? " << (cmp_equal(c, f)?"equal":"not equal")
              << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Note that using `fabs()` means you do not know which of the numbers is larger.

Comment: Note that your output shows a different set of numbers than what you have in your code.

Comment: Keep in mind that epsilon is the smallest value that can be added to 1 to produce a different value. It's far too small to show up when you're looking at numbers like 145.5678.

Comment: thanks for the quick response... Alex : the cout precision probably rounds off  what is shown.. but should not affect the computation; correct?.... also using fabs to show difference ... but my cmp equal doesnot use fabs...

Comment: thanks Pete... so essentially what I get from your comment is to not use long double for small values?...  that is if i use numbers lager than a double and do the diff.... it wil work....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mention, it looks like the long double difference is equal to the *float* precision (it is the double precision, though).

Literal floating points, like literal integers, can be [followed by a suffix](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal) so the conversion makes use of a specific type. By default, the type is double.

There is what you should have to get the wanted precision:

```
float a = 145.5678f;
double b = 145.5678;
long double c = 145.5678l;
```

The 'f' (or 'F') for `floats` and 'l' (or 'L') for `long double`.

Comment: @goffer are you able to upvote this answer and accept it? (the up-arrow and tick to the left of the answer)